# How to run nine patch editor in android studio Ubuntu?

Tags: java, android

I tried to run ninepatch jar from sdk folder using command **java -jar ninepatch.jar** in terminal. My bad, nothing happened. I tried various web based ninepatch editors like [romannurik](https://romannurik.github.io/AndroidAssetStudio/nine-patches.html) 
 which won't serve my purpose.

How can I run ninepatch jar in Ubuntu Linux.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[image]Why do you want to try the hard way,when people has made your life little bit easier.

9patch -> http://romannurik.github.io/AndroidAssetStudio/nine-patches.html

Or,in Android Studio you can right click on your image file from drawable and create 9 patch image. And then you can edit the file.

Comment: The first method im already tried . Can you be more specific on the second method please

Comment: Assuming that you are using Android Studio 1.2.1.1.....
right click on any image in your res->drawable xx folder...In the bottom, you can see an option, Create 9 Patch...Once the 9patch image is created,you can edit the image boundary using ctrl + shift. And many other options.

Comment: You Save the day . it was more easy by doing doubble click on the image and its opens itselfs in .9.png editor because the image already is a .9.png . and i used mouse to adjust pixels . Thank you